# Download customer purchased data

Tags: data-request, shopping

I want to do customer behavior analysis for a retail store. Could you tell me where can i download customer purchased transaction/data?

Answer (score 2):

Try with [Foodmart data set](https://www.google.com/search?q=foodmart%20dataset), a dataset of some 60,000 transactions involving 1,600 different products.